# Optimizing lm() function in a loop

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lm

I'm using the **R** built-in `lm()` function in a loop for estimating a custom statistic:

```
for(i in 1:10000)
  {
    x<-rnorm(n)
    reg2<-lm(x~data$Y)
    Max[i]<-max(abs(rstudent(reg2)))
  }
```

This is really slow when increasing both the loop counter (typically we want to test over 10^6 or 10^9 iterations values for precision issues) and the size of Y.

Having read the following [Stack topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932802/parallel-regression-in-r-maybe-with-snowfall), a very first attemp was to try optimizing the whole using parallel regression (with `calm()`):

```
  cls = makeCluster(4)
  distribsplit(cls, "test")
  distribsplit(cls, "x")
  for(i in 1:10000)
  {
    x<-rnorm(n)
    reg2 <- calm(cls, "x ~ test$Y, data = test")
    Max[i]<-max(abs(reg2$residuals / sd(reg2$residuals)))
  }
```

This ended with a much slower version (by a factor 6) when comparing with the original, unparalleled loop. My assumption is that we ask for creating /destroying the threads in each loop iteration and that slow down the process a lot in **R**.

A second attemp was to use `lm.fit()` according to [this Stack topic](http://Why%20the%20built-in%20lm%20function%20is%20so%20slow%20in%20R?):

```
  for(i in 1:10000)
  {
    x<- rnorm(n)
    reg2<- .lm.fit(as.matrix(x), data$Y)
    Max[i]<-max(abs(reg2$residuals / sd(reg2$residuals)))
  }
```

It resulted in a much faster processing compared to the initial and orgininal version. Such that we now have: `lm.fit()` < `lm()` < `calm()`, speaking of overall processing time.

However, we are still looking for options to improve the efficiency (in term of processing time) of this code. What are the possible options? I assume that making the loop parallel would save some processing time?

**Edit: Minimal Example**

Here is a minimal example:

```
#Import data
sample <- read.csv("sample.txt")
 
#Preallocation
Max <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 100)
 
n <- length(sample$AGE)
x <- matrix(rnorm(100 * n), 100)
 
for(i in 1 : 100)
{
  reg <- lm(x ~ data$AGE)
  Max[i] <- max(abs(rstudent(reg)))
}
```

with the following dataset 'sample.txt':

```
AGE
51
22
46
52
54
43
61
20
66
27
```

From here, we made several tests and noted the following:

- Following @Karo contribution, we generate the matrix of normal samples outside the loop to spare some execution time. We expected a noticeable impact, but run tests indicate that doing so produce the unexpected inverse results (*i.e.* a longer execution time). Maybe the effect reverse when increasing the number of simulations.
- Following @BenBolker uggestion, we also tested `fastlm()` and it reduces the execution time but the results seem to differ (from a factor 0.05) compared to the typical `lm()`

We are still struggling we effectively reducing the execution time. Following @Karo suggestions, we will try to directly pass a vector to `lm()` and investigate parallelization (but failed with `calm()` for an unknown reason).

Comment: What is the value of `n`?

Comment: I can't tell from your code, but it looks like you could grab a couple equations out of a stats book and calculate your `Max[i]`  analytically.

Comment: @RuiBarradas the size of _n_ can typically reach 10^3 and even 10^4 values for some datasets.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the statistic depends on the design of the model, defined by the user.

Comment: first why are you regressing x on y?  Should we not regress y on x?? How can a random generated value be dependent on the data$Y?. Well if at all you are correct then think of doing `m<-rnorm(n*1000,n);lm(m~dat$Y)` This will reduce the number of iterations

Comment: how about `fastLm` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420185/fastlm-is-much-slower-than-lm ?

Comment: I'm with @RuiBarradas: can you tell us what `data$Y`/ the value of `n` are? (Or what a typical value of `n` is/what value you tested with - since you say it varies)

Comment: @RuiBarradas I will make a minimal example to reflect the issue.

Comment: @BenBolker in the benchmark provided fastlm() is slower than lm.fit() that is our best solution at the moment.

Comment: how carefully did you read that answer? as I read Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer, it was slower *if a formula needed to be deparsed*

Comment: @Onyambu We want to estimate the law for the maximum of the studentized residuals. We use simulations for this. Using `rnorm(n*1000, n)` generate 1000*n gaussians of mean n and variance 1 that is not appropriate for our test.

Comment: @BenBolker We changed to `fastlm()` but the results differs from the typical `lm()` i will update the post with a minimal example now.

Comment: @Grasshoper sorry meant to write `m<-matrix(rnorm(n*1000),n);lm(m~dat$Y)`. this will reduce the computation time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wide-ranging comments above, but I'll try to answer a few narrower points.

- I seem to get the same (i.e., `all.equal()` is `TRUE`) results with `.lm.fit` and `fitLmPure`, if I'm careful about random-number seeds:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppEigen)
library(microbenchmark)

nsim <- 1e3
n <- 1e5
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(Y=rnorm(n))

testfun <- function(fitFn=.lm.fit, seed=NULL) {
    if (!is.null(seed)) set.seed(seed)
    x <- rnorm(n)
    reg2 <- fitFn(as.matrix(x), dd$Y)$residuals
    return(max(abs(reg2) / sd(reg2)))
}

## make sure NOT to use seed=101 - also used to pick y - 
## if we have y==x then results are unstable (resids approx. 0)
all.equal(testfun(seed=102), testfun(fastLmPure,seed=102)) ## TRUE
```

`fastLmPure` is fastest (but not by very much):

```
(bm1 <- microbenchmark(testfun(),
                     testfun(lm.fit),
                     testfun(fastLmPure),
                     times=1000))

Unit: milliseconds
                expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max
           testfun() 6.603822 8.234967  8.782436 8.332270  8.745622 82.54284
     testfun(lm.fit) 7.666047 9.334848 10.201158 9.503538 10.742987 99.15058
 testfun(fastLmPure) 5.964700 7.358141  7.818624 7.471030  7.782182 86.47498
```

*If* you wanted to fit many independent responses, rather than many independent predictors (i.e. if you were varying Y rather than X in the regression), you could provide a matrix for Y in `.lm.fit`, rather than looping over lots of regressions, which might be a big win.  If all you care about are "residuals of random regressions" that might be worth a try. (Unfortunately, providing a matrix that combines may separate X vectors runs a *multiple* regression, not many univariate regressions ...)

Parallelizing is worthwhile, but will only scale (at best) according to the number of cores you have available. Doing a single run rather than a set of benchmarks because I'm lazy ...

Running 5000 replicates sequentially takes about 40 seconds for me (modern Linux laptop).

```
system.time(replicate(5000,testfun(fastLmPure), simplify=FALSE))
##    user  system elapsed 
##  38.953   0.072  39.028
```

Running in parallel on 5 cores takes about 13 seconds, so a 3-fold speedup for 5 cores. This will probably be a bit better if the individual jobs are larger, but obviously will never scale better than the number of cores ... (8 cores didn't do much better).

```
library(parallel)
system.time(mclapply(1:5000, function(x) testfun(fastLmPure),
                     mc.cores=5))
##    user  system elapsed 
##  43.225   0.627  12.970
```

It makes sense to me that parallelizing at a higher/coarser level (across runs rather than within lm fits) will perform better.

I wonder if there are analytical results you could use in terms of the [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) of a t distribution ... ?

Answer (score 2):

Since I still can't comment:

Try to avoid loops in R. For some reason you are recalculating those random numbers every iteration. You can do that without a loop:

```
duration_loop <- system.time({
  for(i in 1:10000000)
  {
    x <- rnorm(10)
  }
})

duration <- system.time({
  m <- matrix(rnorm(10000000*10), 10000000)
})
```

Both ways should create 10 random values per iteration/matrix row with the same amount of iterations/rows. Though both ways seem to scale linearly, you should see a difference in execution time, the loop will probably be CPU-bound and the "vectorized" way probably memory-bound.

With that in mind you probably should and most likely can avoid the loop altogether, you can for instance [pass a vector into the lm-function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9238256/13727747). If you still need to be faster after that you can definitely parallelise a number of ways, it would be easier to suggest how with a working example of `data`.